# Viewing database content in PhpStorm (Laravel + SQLite)

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpstorm

After seeding my database with users, I am trying to view the users created through PhpStorm, and I am getting this error.

[image: error]

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

I am using an SQLite database. When I spin up a server, the data will be displayed on my website pages, but it's not showing in PhpStorm.

Comment: Ensure that you have downloaded driver for SQLite in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

I think is your drive problom.

Reference materials：
[Problem creating MySql data source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207037765-Problem-creating-MySql-data-source)

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much!